# Keeping Linux Mint 19.1 Mate from putting the display to sleep

Tags: linux-mint, sleep

I am running Linux Mint 19.1 Mate on a computer running kiosk software. For the love of all things I cannot get it to stop putting the display to sleep. I have set Control Center Power Management settings in the following way:

Actions:
Put computer to sleep when inactive for: Never

Display:
Put display to sleep when inactive for: Never

What might I be missing?

Comment: Is there a screensaver installed? If so, make sure it's disabled as well.